# Having trouble with forward_call - "no applicable tactic"

Tags: verifiable-c

I'm working through Software Foundations book 5.

While working through body_push_increasing (verif-triang),
I'm trying to pass through the call to push. The context before is:

```
Espec : OracleKind
p : val
n : Z
gv : globals
Delta_specs := abbreviate : Maps.PTree.t funspec
Delta := abbreviate : tycontext
H : 0 <= n <= Int.max_signed
i : Z
HRE : i < n
H0 : 0 <= i <= N
POSTCONDITION := abbreviate : ret_assert
===========================
semax Delta (PROP () LOCAL (temp _i (Vint (Int.repr (i + 1)));
                            temp _n (Vint (Int.repr n));
                            temp _p p)
              SEP (stack (decreasing i) p; mem_mgr gv))
            (_push([(_p)%expr; (_i)%expr]);) POSTCONDITION
```

The command I'm trying is

```
forward_call (p, i + 1, decreasing i, gv)
```

which is failing with the message

```
Error: No applicable tactic.
```

The specification for push is

```
DECLARE _push
  WITH p : val, i : Z, l : list Z, gv : globals
  PRE [tptr (tptr (Tstruct _cons noattr)), tint]
    PROP (Int.min_signed <= i <= Int.max_signed)
    PARAMS (p; Vint (Int.repr i)) GLOBALS (gv)
    SEP (stack l p; mem_mgr gv)
  POST [tvoid]
    PROP () RETURN () SEP (stack (i :: l) p; mem_mgr gv)
```

(The C says `typedef struct cons *stack;` instead of having a one-element struct for stack)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

… And it turns out I forgot to put in "gvars gv" in an earlier `forward_while`. Not an obvious pitfall.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, "Error: No applicable tactic" is not a very informative message.  Between VST 2.7 and VST 2.8, several improvements were made in the error diagnostics printed by the "forward" and "forward_call" tactic.  When I get a chance, I'll check whether this case now gives a better message in VST 2.8.

Comment: It doesn't, I can tell you right now. I was using VST 2.8.

Comment: The other issue I'm having is "stackframe is unfolded or modified" when I'm trying to `forward` over a `return`. Any ideas?

Comment: You may have done some sort of "simpl in *" that changed things in the POSTCONDITION.

Comment: The bad error message for missing "gvars gv"  is now VST issue #517. 
https://github.com/PrincetonUniversity/VST/issues/517